How is a quine derived without indexing all partial function?
I am trying to understand how quine is related to Rogers's fixed-point theorem and Kleene's recursion theorem. For exercise, i wrote a quine using the construction of the above theorems and Javascript eval function. But it immediately occurred to me that using eval to index all partial function doesn't work easily for many other languages such as C. (Indeed a C-interpreter can be written in C, but that's definitely not the approach taken by most C quines). Nevertheless there're quines without eval. How can such a quine written in C derived theoretically from the fixed-point theorem mentioned above (or from any other computability theorem)?

Any Turing-complete language admits a self-interpreter, so you can theoretically write an eval function in C. (You can also cheat by writing the source code to a file and calling GCC via system(3), but that's less interesting...)
